# Write text in C with write()

Tags: c

I want to write text to a file. I have to use write() instead of fwrite()

```
void write(char *buffer, char *target){
int fh;
    if((fh=open(target, O_RDWR)) >= 0){
                    printf("It works\n");
    } else {
        printf("Cannot open\n");
    }

    if((write(fh, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) >= 0){
        printf("-> It works\n");
    } else {
        printf("Cannot write\n");
    }
    close(fh);
}
```

I am able to write to the file but I cannot read it. The buffer contains some text but when I open the target file all I get is \00\00\00\00

I heard it is possible with fopen and fwrite but I have to use open() and write(). I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Does this compile? I'd expect too many parameters, since you called your own function write(), too.

Comment: @Chris it would if someone is using a C++ compiler for their C-code, which is never a good idea when you're trying to get at least compile-portable C.

Answer (score 3):

```
  if((write(fh, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) >= 0){
```

You need to pass in the length of the buffer to your function.  sizeof(buffer) will return
the size of a char* data type (4 (32-bit)or 8 (64-bit) bytes).

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to define your own `write()` because it will alias the system call C wrapper that is also called write.

Plus, if the buffer has a string in it, you will want to write exactly its length.

```
void mywrite(char *buffer, char *target) {
. . .
    write(fh, buffer, strlen(buffer))
```

Comment: Mind: This isn't binary safe. Better pass the length

Comment: Sure, but I always wonder how much upper division material to include in an SO answer. All the assumptions *are* technically a part of an example's API.

Answer (score 1):

a) Your own function name is write

b) Use strlen instead of sizeof for last parameter of write.

So

a) Change your function name to something else other than write.

b) Instead of sizeof, use strlen.